# How to set font-weight of certain letters in a word

Tags: css

I'm building a web page based on the work of a designer. There is a word in which the first 6 letters are in bold while the rest of the letters have a normal weight.

```css
.somediv .moreweight {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv">
  <h1>SOME TEXT AND THIS IS THE <span class="moreweight">COMPLI</span>CATED THING</h1>
</div>
```

Nothing happens on my page, the whole text in the h1 tag has the same weight.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Does your font have a font-weight `900`?

Comment: Heading tags are bold by default...so you're not changing anything really.

Comment: it works, just try setting the weight to something smaller and you'll see

Comment: Most (if not all) browsers render headings in bold by default, and according to MDN, "If a weight greater than 500 is given, the closest available darker weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available lighter weight)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font you're using probably has no `900` weight defined, so defaults to `700` which is already being used by the `h1` tag by default.

> Quite often there are only a few weights available for a particular font family. When a weight is specified for which no face exists, a face with a nearby weight is used.
>
> — [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-weight)

The two options you have here are to:

1. Incorporate a font which does support a `font-weight` of `900` along with `700`.
2. Make the `h1` element a lighter weight which your current font already supports (e.g. `400`):

   ```css
   .somediv h1 {
     font-weight: 400;
   }

   .somediv .moreweight {
     font-weight: 900;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="somediv">
     <h1>SOME TEXT AND THIS IS THE <span class="moreweight">COMPLI</span>CATED THING</h1>
   </div>
   ```

---

An alternative approach would be to use colours to give the impression of different importance. A light grey by default and a darker grey for the *bold* part could work here:

```css
.somediv h1 {
  color: #616161;
}

.somediv .moreweight {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv">
  <h1>SOME TEXT AND THIS IS THE <span class="moreweight">COMPLI</span>CATED THING</h1>
</div>
```

I'm certainly no designer though, so don't be surprised if your designer doesn't like that solution!

Comment: Thank you very much, your first suggestion worked. I didn't know that fonts don't support all possible weights by default.

Comment: @GuitarExtended happy to help! Very often fonts will only support 400 (*normal*) and 700 (*bold*) weights by default.

Answer (score 2):

Font weights are defined in the typography file. If your typography have weights of 300 and 400 you can't define a 900 weight. So be sure that you are using a font and including all the styles that allows you to use 900 of weight.

Comment: Sorry for my last comments. I think that users penalized me because my offensive words. My apologizes.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you for the information. I haven't accepted your answer because the one above is more complete, but yours was useful nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah don't worry. It's a good question that fits with very much answers. Good luck!